# PowerShell exit() kills shell and ISE

Tags: powershell, exit, powershell-ise

So I've written a series of functions and inserted them into a PS Module (.psm1). One of which is a simple ErrorAndExit function that writes a message to STDERR and then calls `exit(1);`, a habit to allow easy redirection of error messages. While debugging my script, in either the normal PowerShell or ISE, if I call a function that in turn calls ErrorAndExit, it not only exits the script, but exits the entire PowerShell process. Both the terminal and ISE die immediately. The terminal, I might just understand, but ISE?! The most frustrating part is, of course, that I cannot see the error message before the window disappears.

I believe this has something to do with how I'm debugging - I've defined a lot of functions that happen in a chain, and have commented out the call to start the chain. I'm importing the script and calling the functions from the prompt. As the script is designed for automation, killing the whole PS process will not be a problem in actual use, but I need to see what the debug output is.

The function in question, in Common.psm1:

```
function errorAndExit([string]$message)
{
    logError($message);
    exit(1);
}
```

Where `logError` passes `$message` to `Write-Error`. An example function where this call causes PS or ISE to die:

```
function branch([string]$branchName, [int]$revision, [string]$jenkinsURL, [switch]$incrementTrunk)
{
    Set-Variable -Name ErrorActionPreference -Value Stop;
    log("Script starting, parameters branchName=$branchName, revision=$revision, jenkinsURL=$jenkinsURL");
    if (-not ($branchName -match "\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d"))
    {
        errorAndExit("Provided branch name $branchName is not a valid YYYY.MM.R string");
    }
...
```

My Common.psm1 module is being imported with a simple `Import-Module -Force "$PSScriptRoot\Common";`. When called from the PS prompt:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> branch -branchName abc
```

causes either PowerShell or ISE to exit completely.

I am coming to PowerShell from a Bash mentality and have written scripts as such (getting used to passing objects however), but this is not behaviour I would expect from any scripting language.

Comment: Don't use `exit`, set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` instead if you want your script to stop on error

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I'm already doing that, see the code snippet. This is about raising the error in the first place.

Comment: @Gargravarr - we don't use parentheses - `( )` - to execute functions in PowerShell. This is valid syntactically but wrong semantically. `logError($message)` should be `logError $message`, `exit(1)` should be `exit 1`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Powershell ISE, the `exit` command closes the entire IDE, not just the current command tab.

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13223112-would-be-better-if-the-exit-command-in-powershell

Your use of `exit` is a little flawed in your errorAndExit function.  As mentioned, either a `throw` or a `return $false` and evaluating the results would be a better bet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Throw is what I need; calling exit() is how I would normally do this in other languages, where I am sure I want the script to cease immediately due to bad data. I'm still confused at the decision to make exit() kill the entire PowerShell.exe process, even within a script.

Comment: Yea, Powershell's implementation of functions is a little funky.  I always think `return` but really all a function is doing is adding to the pipeline, so you have to be careful that you're not adding to the pipeline with some other  commandlet.  `Throw` works, but only if your trapping is in place.

Comment: Alternatively Write-Error provides some more options for generating the error and fits in better with the PowerShell language.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you can't just `throw` your error message. If you must use the return code from `exit`, but don't want to do that in ISE, consider changing your function:

```
function errorAndExit([string]$message)
{
    logError $message
    if ($Host.Name -eq 'Windows PowerShell ISE Host') {
        throw $message
    } else {
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you're right, I wasn't using the correct process. I'm still finding it odd that exit() implicitly kills the entire PowerShell.exe process.

Answer (score 3):

try the [Throw](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847766.aspx) keyword, it's for raising exceptions you can later use in a try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks like what I need